# Will smart pointer automatically release space hold by array?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory

If I apply memory by `shared_ptr<double> p(new int);`, the space applied will be automatically released once the `use_count` of `p` turns to 0. But if I apply for an array memory by `shared_ptr<double> p(new int[10]);`, will the whole array memory be released, or only the space of the first value is released(and cause potential memory leak)?

```
Matrix::Matrix(size_t m, size_t n) {
  shared_ptr<double> data_(new double[m * n]);
  m_ = m;
  n_ = n;
}
```

Comment: If you use `shared_ptr<double[]>` it will handle the array properly.

Comment: Is there a reason you need shared ownership in the first place? I would like to think a matrix is the sole owner of its values so a `std::vector<double>` should suffice. Or arguably your matrix should be a class template with fixed size m*n (for better performance) and then your `data_` can be a `std::array<double,N*M>`

Comment: I'm not adept at C++, and thought that using smart pointer is the easiest way to prevent memory leak.

Comment: @LionnelEmerson None of the types in the standard library (or any properly designed C++ types following basic rules like RAII/rule-of-0/3/5 for that matter) will leak any memory when used correctly. Ironically, using `shared_ptr` where it isn't really needed is going to increase the likelihood of memory leaks due to accidental circular ownership. `shared_ptr` should only be used if you can't decide on a single owner of the object. Leaks can be avoided by never using `new`/`delete` directly and using types like `std::vector`/`std::unique_ptr` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default constructor of `std::shared_ptr<double>` will use a non-array `delete` expression as the deleter to destroy the managed object.

Therefore passing the result of an array-new expression to it causes undefined behavior when the managed object is destroyed.

Since C++17 you can use `std::shared_ptr<double[]>` instead which will by default use `delete[]` in the deleter and since C++20 there is also an overload for [`std::make_shared`/`std::make_shared_for_overwrite`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) that can be used as `std::make_shared<double[]>(m*n)` to create the array and `std::shared_ptr<double[]>` managing it, so you don't need the manual `new` expression (which is something that should generally be avoided in most situations).

With C++11 you need to provide a custom deleter that uses `delete[]` or wrap the array in a class type.

Either way though, usually a `std::vector<double>` would be more appropriate than a `std::shared_ptr<double[]>` anyway. Consider whether you really need the shared ownership that `shared_ptr` provides (which is more often not the case). If you do, you can also use `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<double>>` instead (but that has one extra indirection).